# sequelize.sync() not working for snowflake. Throw an error:'this.queryGenerator.tableExistsQuery is not a function'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to create table in snowflakedb but throw error.

here is sample code

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({
  userName: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: DataTypes.STRING,
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'USER_TABLE', freezeTableName: true });

(async () => {
await sequelize.sync();

const jane = User.build({
    userName: 'jane',
    password: 'jane'
    });
    await jane.save();
    console.log(jane.get({ plain: true }));
    console.log(sequelize.models.USER_TABLE);

})();
```

Comment: What version of NODE ad Sequelize are you using?  https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/

Comment: node: 16,   "sequelize": "^6.6.5","snowflake-sdk": "^1.6.11"

Comment: Do you have enough ")" in your block above?  I don't see a closing paren for the "(async".

Comment: @JimDemitriou ya.. i can able to query data from snowflake, but not able to sync() or create table in snowflake. basically i can able to perform all operation via literal/raw query. not through sequelize model

Comment: We're at the limits of my knowledge in this space ... I have to defer to others with experience using sequelize.